# how to create the Layer Properties button as geoexplorer?

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk, geoexplorer

I was in the debug mode.And I create a Layer Properties button ,but it is only show the title.
the code for it,

```
 * @require plugins/LayerProperties.js
--------------------
{
  ptype: "gxp_layerproperties",
  actionTarget: ["tree.tbar"]
}
-----------------------
```

How can I do to get a button as Layer Properties on geoexplorer tree panel that has 3 tags,like about,display and available styles? Especially the display tag is more important to move opacity slidebar.

Comment: What type of layer are you using it on? It generally only works on WMS layers.

Comment: I used WMS layers.I got the layer properties button, but it only show the title bar.

Comment: Do your WMS layers come from a WMS source? You may want to look at this example and try to align your code with it: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/examples/viewer.js

Comment: I think I must change the title for this question. How I can do to add a slider opacity under every raster layer?